# Boolean Algebra on Circuits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, discrete-optimization

Can I use boolean algebra to simplify electric circuits installed on buildings, establishments (etc.) using the blueprint of the buildings fluorescent lamp circuit system and electric fan circuit system?

Comment: That's within the realm of possibility, although I have no idea if you can do it or not. I would have to know you a lot better.

Comment: Why? Please, your help and expertise would be greatly appreciated. .

Comment: Why *what*?${}{}$ Do you mean *How*?

Comment: Nevermind the why sir, lets take how sir, how could you know me a lot better??

Comment: Haha. "Money for nothing and chicks for free"... Nice try. Boolean algebra deals with logic gates, not really the circuits you are thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

Your question probably aims at illustrating different meanings of the word `circuit`.

A general `electric circuit` consists of power source(s), cables, switches, junctions, sockets and power consumers. One could apply boolean algebra to simplify a configuration of parellel/serial switches used to operate the same device. This would then be a form of `switching logic`. The usual simplifications of electrical circuits strive to reduce the cable length or improve the stability of power supply.

However, the technical representation of a `boolean function` is a circuit whitch consists of digital gates (AND, OR, NAND, NOR, XOR, ...) or switches. Such a circuit is not supposed to convey electrical power but logical information. The physical details of the interconnection between components do not influence the logical behaviour looking at it from the abstract level of boolean logic.

Below the line, my answer is: **No, you can't!**